# GET method request is working for all other type of requests

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jpa

After deploying the resource to the server, we started for the API testing.
Any how API's will starts with https://.. for these requests GET POST..every methods are working proper,But if i change it to http instead of https For every methods it is working good, where as GET method API (`@Getmapping("/getalluserdetails")`) will response even if you make a request from POST,PUT etc..

I tried with this changes also

```java
@Override 
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
}
```

```java
@GetMapping("/getalluserdetails")
    public UserDetailResponser getAllUserDetails(
            @Valid @RequestHeader("accessToken") 
            @NotEmpty(message = "accessToken is mandatory") String bearer,
            @RequestHeader("mappingId") 
            @NotEmpty(message = "mappingId is mandatory") String mappingId) {
    }
```

This method accepting request even if i send a request from POST this is only if i change it to http://.....request

Actual thing (`@Getmapping("/getalluserdetails")`) should not work for other methods

Comment: Please format your code properly. It's not readable.

Comment: Do you have any class level "REST" annotations?

Comment: Yes i have..(@restcontroller)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the  @RequestMapping annotation to define what type of request should be mapped to a function.

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET })
@GetMapping("/getalluserdetails")
public UserDetailResponser getAllUserDetails(@Valid @RequestHeader("accessToken") @NotEmpty(message = "accessToken is mandatory") String bearer,@RequestHeader("mappingId") @NotEmpty(message = "mappingId is mandatory") String mappingId) {
}
```

Comment: [`@GetMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html) "is" exactly a `@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET })` shrtcut

Comment: Again i added your code now it is showing like
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'userControllerAPI' method 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'userControllerAPI' method ...

This error may be I added @requestmapping on TOP of the class i think so..

Comment: use `@RequestMapping(method= {RequestMethod.GET}, value = "/getalluserdetails")` before method and remove `@GetMapping` annotation.

Comment: @Mohankumar have you checked above solution?

Comment: Yes but the response is same..it is working for other methods

Comment: @Mohankumar can u specify how u are sending the request to the server ?

Comment: 1)When I use this path it is working fine(https) https://35.12.17.95/injofy/api/user/getallJobpostsforuser
2)I change like this to(http) ->http://35.12.17.95/injofy/api/user/getallJobpostsforuser
This GET method working for all other requests

Comment: you are just changing the https to http. This has nothing to do with GET or POST. It is just used for SSL.

Comment: I got it is secured but it is working, atleast it should not happen right..? for POST(http) request methods if i change it to GET it will deny..why it's not the same in GET(http) Method